# php5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 is not showing errors with default error handler

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I recently installed apache2 and php5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04
In the php.ini for apache and cli I've set all parameters with the correct configuration (I think):

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
track_errors = On
error_log = "/var/log/php_errors.log"
```

The file that error_log points is writable.

And I can make errors to display in the command linke nor web browser.

I spended hours searching the web and the only think I managed to work is setting manually the error handled in one script with:

```
set_error_handler("var_dump");
```

When changing the error handler some info is printed (the mysql error that I forced):

```
$ php informe_presupuestos.php
/var/www/buv/lib/sqlquery.class.php:88:
int(2)
/var/www/buv/lib/sqlquery.class.php:88:
string(72) "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"
/var/www/buv/lib/sqlquery.class.php:88:
string(66) "/var/www/buv/lib/sqlquery.class.php"
/var/www/buv/lib/sqlquery.class.php:88:
int(88)
/var/www/buv/lib/sqlquery.class.php:88:
array(1) {
  'result_id' =>
  string(4) "pres"
}
```

I also tried to restore_error_handler() at the beggining of the script, but doesn't works.

Any ideas of how I can enable the error displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Little wired what you have, because normaly it should work, but i dont now whats in your `.php` so mybe try this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
register_shutdown_function(function(){while(ob_get_level()>0)ob_end_flush();});
```

And by the way, what is the content of `/var/log/php_errors.log` while you are testing your script.

Note from http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php:

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called.

So if you dont realy now, you better use the default error handler.

Comment: I tried your code at the begining of the script and nothing is displayed. The error log is empty.

Comment: Only for a validation in full. please add `new NonClass();` after the `register` line and try again and say if you see something.

Comment: Also for `php.ini`: you have to restart apache after changes `service apache2 restart`. And have you change only the `cli` php.ini or the `cgi` version too? Or maybe mixed these two?

Comment: After restarting the machine, the scenario changed a bit. Now the scripts called from the command line show the error and the stack trace. Good :)
The scripts executed from the browser doesn't show the error unless error_reporting() and display_errors are set in the code. Seems that the /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini is not read

Comment: When declaring a non-existent class the error is shown normally. But when the error comes from an incorrect MySQL syntax nothing happens.